# how to pass a variable from javascript to php or directly to db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables, get

I'm trying to pass a variable from javascript to php using this simple code and then I want to put it into my database:

```
<?php
 mysql_select_db($database_Connessione_server,$Connessione_server); //connection to db
 $ind = 1;

<script>
var i = 10;

<?php
    $ind = $GET['i'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (".$ind.")");                
?> </script>
```

but I keep getting the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
The connection to the db works, but the GET method doesn't get the value 'i'. Getting the type of the variable 'ind' I get undefined index i.
Can someone help me to solve the problem? Is there another method to insert variables into database using javascript?

--EDIT---
What I want is to understand why my code doesn't work and what that error means in my case.
I already read the answers to the other questions but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question, next time. The linked question appeared in the suggestions, and should have been visible while you were writing the question.

Comment: the unexpected token is `<` in `<script>` on line 5, php doesn't know what `<script>` means

Comment: @andrew Thank you for your help, I solved one problem but I'm still getting this: " Notice: Undefined index:i " on line 9 ($ind = $GET['i'];). Can you please explain me why?